# Correlate application logs (Coldfusion/J2EE) with IIS logs to debug client network problems

Tags: performance, http, iis, logging, isapi

I've seen some clients complaining about slowness of my website lately and I'm pretty sure that the problem is related to their network.  I'd like to be able to justify this to myself more thoroughly and also be able to more proactively reach out to clients that appear to be having network issues before they come banging on my door.

If I was running ASP.Net I would try to use the [Response.AppendToLog Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524861.aspx) and append a token so that I could tie back everything back to my custom application level logging (user, client, processing time, etc.).  I can't seem to find a way to do that without ASP.net.  I'm guessing it's built into ASP's ISAPI.  My requests are going through IIS to JRun's ISAPI to Coldfusion (*.cfm/*.cfc files).

I'm most interested in knowing **how long it took the client to receive the content**  not just the time it took to process the request.

If there are other places/information that I'm not considering that's worth looking at, please let me know.  Perhaps I should log information from HTTP.sys somehow?

I know that I could set a cookie on every request and have that logged by IIS, I was just hoping there would be a better solution.

Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

See [Jiffy](http://code.google.com/p/jiffy-web/).  It "is an end-to-end real-world web page instrumentation and measurement suite."

The [introductory video](http://blip.tv/file/1018527) gives a good overview.